# No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it apache wampserver

Tags: apache, server, wamp

I have a running apache server that generates the following error when i issue a command `ab -n -c 200 http://example.com`

`abr_socket_connection():No connection could be made` because the target machine actively refused it

This is because it may be happening and how to fix it.

This is running in windows serer 2016 and `WampServer`

Thank you.

Comment: Be sure you have defined that hostname at your host level. Also try doing less concurrent request, you could reach the limit of your set up.

Comment: Hi thanks for you answer 
We perform a load test 7 hours and when executing ab we generate this error
so I do not know if it's a limitation of ab or it's a problem of sockets